# Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address") return null in Android O

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-bluetooth, android-8.0-oreo

When I'm trying to get Bluetooth Address on Android O device by this way:

```
private String getBlutoothAddress(Context mContext){  
    // Check version API Android
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
       
    String macAddress;

    int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (currentApiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        macAddress = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address"); 
    } else {
        // Do this for phones running an SDK before lollipop
        macAddress = myBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();            
    }
}
```

All code above working well until I use that code for Android O (8.0) it returns macAddress = null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your app would need to hold the `LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS` permission:

> **Settings.Secure.bluetooth_address**: Device Bluetooth MAC address. In O, this is only available to apps holding the LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS permission.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html

However, the [`LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS` permission is a system permission](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#3027) so in practice your app cannot have it.

Comment: I follow your way before  asking but code not work because " The LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS permission is a system permission so in practice your app cannot have it." like you say . So don't have any solution to get Bluetooth Address on Android O ?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve by obtaining the address?

Comment: I use bluetooth address to identify my device in my app . You have any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address") return null in andriod 10

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to identify your device, you can use `getImei()` from [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getImei()) API. Note that you will need to [request](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html) `READ_PHONE_STATE` [permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) from the user since it has the dangerous protection level.

If such API proves to be not reliable on your tests, please look for alternative ways (which have their own drawbacks) from this other two questions: [Unique Android Device ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) and [Serial Number of Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device).